# Why is this the point to which $q$ has moved?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

A unit-speed plane curve $\gamma (s)$ rolls without slipping along a straight line $l$ parallel to a unit vector $a$, and initially touches $l$ at a point $p = \gamma (0)$. Let $q$ be a point fixed relative to $\gamma$. Let $\Gamma (s)$ be the point to which $q$ has moved when $\gamma$ has rolled a distance $s$ along $l$ (note that $\Gamma$ will not usually be unit-speed). Let $\theta (s)$ be the angle between $a$ and the tangent vector $\dot \gamma$ . Show that
$$\Gamma (s) = p + sa + \rho_{−\theta (s)}(q − \gamma (s)),$$ 
where $\rho_{\phi}$ is the rotation about the origin through an angle $\phi$. Show further that
$$\dot \Gamma (s) \cdot  \rho_{−\theta(s)}(q − \gamma (s)) = 0.$$

$$$$

We have that $\Gamma (s)$ is the point to which $q$ has moved when $\gamma$ has rolled a distance $s$ along $l$, why isn't then $\Gamma (s)=q+s$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

What does it mean that "$\gamma (s)$ rolls without slipping along a straight line $l$" ?

Comment: There are some points which are not entirely clear here, but I can make some guesses. First, you say that $q$ is fixed relative to $\gamma$. What exactly does this mean? Does $q$ have some fixed distance with respect to $\gamma$ which is realized in some $q^\prime\in \gamma$? Then you say that $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and the tangent vector $\dot{\gamma}$, but you do not say where $\dot{\gamma}$ has to be evaluated. Finally, your question (why is $\Gamma$ not given by the expression you are suggesting) is also not well posed, since $s$ is not a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: $q$ is a fixed point on $\gamma$. I don't really know where $\dot \gamma$ has to be evaluated. Do you have an idea how we find the formule for $\Gamma$ ?  @Thomas